# Is there any high-level .Net SDK for AWS?

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Does anyone know of a high-level SDK for interacting with AWS? The SDK provided by Amazon is good and the REST/SOAP API well documented but I often find that I still end up having to write common, high level operations myself.

Take for instance, the S3 client, it gives you the ability to put/get/list objects, etc. but it's sadly missing the ability to do high level operations such as create folder, move file to a different folder, etc.

You could use tools like Cloud Berry or the Amazon web console to do this sort of things manually, but sometimes you will want to build some automation into your app like periodically backing up some data into a backup folder with time stamp.

Cheers,

**UPDATE:** sorry if I left the question a little too open, seeing as AWS covers so many different things, but in particular I'm looking for a high-level library for S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some open source projects on CodePlex. The entire list is at http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=AWS&ac=8

Comment: we've been using SimpleSavant as ORM for SimpleDB and it works really well but so far I haven't seen a project of that quality for S3 or other services like SQS, will go through the list and check them out, thanks

Comment: Please avoid adding signatures to your posts, as per the FAQ - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 5):

The [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) provides some high-level interfaces for S3. The [Amazon.S3.IO](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/Index.html??topic=html/N_Amazon_S3_IO.htm) namespace contains FileInfo and DirectoryInfo abstractions and the [Amazon.S3.Transfer](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/Index.html??topic=html/N_Amazon_S3_Transfer.htm) utilities allow for simple upload and download, including for large files.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you need you can find [CloudBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-cloud.php) package of our SecureBlackbox product useful. CloudBlackbox provides an almost-uniform API for accessing different cloud storages, and offers built-in encryption mechanisms. CloudBlackbox offers high-level API for .NET.

Answer (score 0):

A newer version of AWS sdk implements S3FileInfo and S3DirectoryInfo. You can use it like .net FileInfo and DirectoryInfo.

The problem is that it does not support large files.